# Cannot create class object or array of class objects

Tags: swift

I'm working on a project thatand am simply trying to create a object instance of a simple custom class:

import Foundation

```
class Set {

    private var gam1: Int!
    private var gam2: Int!

    init (gam1: Int, gam2: Int) {
        self.gam1 = gam1
        self.gam2 = gam2
    }

    //returns set info as array
    func getStats () -> [Int] {
        let arr = [gam1!, gam2!]
        return arr
    }

}
```

The class simply stores a few variables for use later and I want an array of such objects to store several values. However, when I try to create a n instance of the class in a different class I get errors:

```
import Foundation
    class AnotherClass {

var mySet = Set(gam1: 6, gam2: 5) //error 1

   //array of set objects
    var setArray = [Set]()  // error 2

    //returns array of set objects
    func getSets () -> [Set] {  //error 3
    return setArray
    }

}
```

The errors state:

1. Cannot find an initializer for type 'Set' that accepts an argument list of type '(gam1: Int, gam2: Int)'
2. Cannot invoke initializer for type '[Set]' with no arguments

and

3. Reference to generic type 'Set' requires arguments in <...>

Any ideas of what the issue is here? could the 'Set' name of the class be conflicting with a reserved keyword?

Many thanks,
Kw

Comment: Rename your class. It seems to interfere with the existing `Set` collection type.

Answer (score 3):

> The issue that you are having is due to the naming conflict between `Set` in the Swift standard library and the one you defined.

This is *never* a good idea. Instead, give it a more descriptive name (and one that doesn't conflict with anything else). For instance, call it `gamHolder` and initialize it `gamHolder(gam1: <an int>, gam2: <another int>)`.

> Also, if you have defined variables inside the init function they do not need to be forced unwrapped optionals.

For example:

```
class myClass {
    var myInt: Int

    init(anInt: Int) {
        myInt = anInt
    }
}
```

Comment: This was definitely an issue however I am still getting a problem after creating a new class renamed TennisSet and pasting the code in with a class name also of TennisSet:

Comment: XCode is saying that the class is an unresolved identifier:

Comment: Could you put your code on pastebin? It would help to get some context.

Answer (score 0):

You defined 2 parameters in your `init` method (since `gam1` and `gam2` are not optional). So, you have 2 solutions:

1 - You add parameters into your `init` call (like this):

```
 var mySet = Set(gam1: 1, gam2: 2)
```

2 - You change `gam1` and `gam2` to optionals and you add a zero parameters init:

```
class Set {

    private var gam1: Int?
    private var gam2: Int?

    init() {
    }

    init(gam1: Int, gam2: Int) {
        self.gam1 = gam1
        self.gam2 = gam2
    }

    // returns set info as array
    func getStats() -> [Int] {
        let arr = [gam1!, gam2!]
        return arr
    }
}
```

So, you will be able to call it like this: `var mySet = Set()`

Also: be careful: `Set` is a class used in the Swift standard library. It's never a good idea to use same class names than Swift Standard Library. A name like `TenisSet` would be better.

**Edit:**

Here is a final working example with a renamed class:

```
class TenisSet {

    private var gam1: Int?
    private var gam2: Int?

    init() {
    }

    init(gam1: Int, gam2: Int) {
        self.gam1 = gam1
        self.gam2 = gam2
    }

    // returns set info as array
    func getStats() -> [Int] {
        let arr = [gam1!, gam2!]
        return arr
    }
}

class AnotherClass {

    var mySet = TenisSet()

    // array of set objects
    var setArray = [TenisSet]() 

    // returns array of set objects
    func getSets() -> [TenisSet] {
        return setArray
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks the <Set> keyword was definitely part of the problem but I still cant reference a new class called TennisSet.

Comment: I edited my answer with a working example at the bottom